# Safari can't load any page, but chrome can

Tags: wifi, safari, google-chrome, websites

If I connect to a specific wifi network with my MacBook Pro, Safari can't load any site, but Chrome can. This problem occurs only one wifi network (but unfortunately I have to use this network). I've tried it with Sierra and High Sierra too.
How could I solve this problem? What should I try?